# i have already bind the dropdwonlist control with database, on selection from dropdown it shoulf display the data in grid

Tags: gridview

i have already bind the DropDownlist control with database, on selection from DropDownlist it should display the data in grid

Answer (score 0):

assign the indexchanged event to the dropdown and populate and databind the grid in the eventhandler ...

```
MyDropDown.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ClickDropReports);

 protected void ClickDropReports(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //this is the event handler where you do 
  //get the data for the GridView and databind it 
}
```